# Convert string input to double in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
<Window x:Class="MySecondApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySecondApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.393,0.48">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="175,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="175,69,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="FirstInput" Content="First Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.855,0.173" Height="23"/>
        <Label x:Name="SecondInput" Content="Second Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="190,212,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am beginner to C#. I am trying to make a simple calculator which will only add two numbers. I have taken two Text boxes. Now I want to convert the 
string datatype of *FirstInput* and *SecondInput* to double. what's the command for that?

Comment: If you data bind those text boxes to doubles, the conversion and validation will be handled automatically by WPF.  If you avoid data binding in WPF you're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, and also provide you with the start of some validation.

```
double firstInputDouble;

if(!double.TryParse(FirstInput.Content, out firstInputDouble)){
    // something went wrong....
}
```

Repeat the same for your second double, then you will have them both in the format that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tryparse to avoid exceptions

```
double res;
Double.TryParse(YourString, out res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstInputAsDouble = Convert.ToDouble(FirstInput.Content);
```

or

```
double firstInputAsDouble;
double.TryParse(FirstInput.Content, out firstInputAsDouble);
```

Comment: Yeah right. I want to pass two double into two textboxes and the third text box will show the sum of those two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
//creating two double variables
double FirstInput_double,SecondInput_double;
//Using the Convert.ToDouble() function to do the conversion
FirstInput_double = Convert.ToDouble(FirstInput);
SecondInput_double = Convert.ToDouble(SecondInput);
//do what you want with the double converted values
```